# Database numeric field starting with 0

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, types

I am using a field named as area_code that has int data-type in MySQL. But it doesn't allow me to store exact values like 0781, 0727, 0788 Bcoz they are starting with 0. 
It stores the values as 781, 727 and 788 i.e. it truncates 0 from the values  and save it.

Please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
drop table if exists foo;
create table foo
(
area_code smallint(4) unsigned zerofill not null default 0
)
engine=innodb;

insert into foo (area_code) values (781),(727);

select * from foo;
+-----------+
| area_code |
+-----------+
|      0781 |
|      0727 |
+-----------+
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Fine if your area codes are always guaranteed to be 4 digits long with left-most 0s.  Not the case, for example, in the UK (e.g. 01865 is the code for Oxford and 020 is the code for London).

Comment: This is not a good idea. Leading zeroes in area codes are not fillers to pad the area code number to four places or something like that. A leading zero means "enter the 0 on your phones keyboard/dial", two leading zeroes mean a completely different thing to the phone network. As borrible already said, this is very likely to break when you have to store international area codes.

Answer (score 6):

Area codes are not numbers, but text (which contains digits only). Declare area_code as a  varchar field of appropriate size.

Answer (score 3):

Use a character based data-type rather than a numeric data-type.

Answer (score 3):

Use VARCHAR, because you don't need to make any arithmetic actions with area codes

Answer (score 3):

if you want your result as 4 digits you can maybe do it in this way:

```
select lpad(area_code, 4, '0') from zipcode_list;
```

now you can store the 3 numbers in your database and returning the zero before.